# how to draw a line between two component in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

i have two component that one of them is child of another and i need to draw a line between them with mouseDown and MouseUp
the problem is: i dont know how to find real x,y of shape1 and shape2

(component is a recursive component that i wrote)

there is piece of my code but it dont work correctly

its my component:

```
<mx:Box id="component" borderStyle="solid" width="100%" height="500">
    <local:compforSM id="compForSS" label="پرسپکتیو" rotateLabel="true" statusColor="{0x008000}" layoutType="{compforSM.HORIZENTAL}" width="80%" height="80%" creationComplete="createComplete()" />
```

my MouseDownHandler :

```
private function mouseDown(e:MouseDownOrUpEvent):void {
if (e.target != null) {
if(firstObject == null){
firstObject = e.target;
        firstPoint = component.localToGlobal(new Point(component.x, component.y));
        firstPoint.x = mouseX - firstPoint.x;
        firstPoint.y = mouseY - firstPoint.y;
        }

        }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done this in a while, but I think you first would want to convert into a global point by using the components upper left coordinate.

Then, if not drawing on stage but on another component, you would want to convert the global point back into a local point relative to that component.

Something like this:

```
var globalPoint:Point = component.localToGlobal(new Point(0, 0));

var newLocalPoint:Point = componentWhereYouWantToDrawIfNotStage.globalToLocal( globalPoint );
```

EDIT:

I don't know what it is exactly that you are trying to accomplish. I assume you want to draw somewhere to the mouse pointer - but not sure. Also I don't know what you mean by recursive component.

Here is some code to draw a line from the center of an inner to the center of an outer component. I use a canvas on top of all components to ensure the line is visible, no matter what the components may be.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="onCreationComplete();">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

        private function onCreationComplete():void
        {
            var globalInnerPoint:Point = innerComponent.localToGlobal( new Point( innerComponent.width / 2, innerComponent.height / 2 ) );
            var globalOuterPoint:Point = outerCcomponent.localToGlobal( new Point( outerCcomponent.width / 2, outerCcomponent.height / 2 ) );

            var canvasLayerInnerPoint:Point = canvasLayer.globalToLocal( globalInnerPoint );
            var canvasLayerOuterPoint:Point = canvasLayer.globalToLocal( globalOuterPoint);

            canvasLayer.graphics.lineStyle(4, 0xFF0000);
            canvasLayer.graphics.moveTo( canvasLayerInnerPoint.x, canvasLayerInnerPoint.y );
            canvasLayer.graphics.lineTo( canvasLayerOuterPoint.x, canvasLayerOuterPoint.y );
        }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <mx:Box id="outerCcomponent" borderStyle="solid" width="100%" height="500">
        <mx:Box id="innerComponent" width="80%" height="80%" borderStyle="solid"/>
    </mx:Box>

    <mx:Canvas id="canvasLayer" height="100%" width="100%" />

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thank you Stefan. the first line helped but the upper left corner is not exactly upper left corner of my component,its a little downer!! And second line is referring to an unknown point !!!

Comment: Added some code to draw a line from the center of the inner component to the center of the outer component. Hope this helps.